# MSSQL driver is not loaded by Tomcat

Tags: java, sql-server, tomcat, jdbc

I am trying to deploy my webapp to a Tomcat container, but I get an exception stating that no driver for my database can be found. Locally I test the app on Jetty and the driver-jar is provided by Maven. I copied the driver-jar to the lib folder in the Tomcat home folder, but I still get this exception:

```
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:sqlserver:<address of the database>
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:604) ~[?:1.7.0_21]
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:243) ~[?:1.7.0_21]
    at com.mypackage.ConnectionFactory.createConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:34) ~[ConnectionFactory.class:?]
    at com.mypackage.SimpleWebSession.authenticate(SimpleWebSession.java:63) [SimpleWebSession.class:?]
    at org.apache.wicket.authroles.authentication.AuthenticatedWebSession.signIn(AuthenticatedWebSession.java:65) [AuthenticatedWebSession.class:6.15.0]
    at com.mypackage.SimpleWebSession.signIn(SimpleWebSession.java:118) [SimpleWebSession.class:?]
    at com.mypackage.SignInPage$1.onSubmit(SignInPage.java:67) [SignInPage$1.class:?]
    at org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.Form.delegateSubmit(Form.java:1272) [Form.class:6.15.0]
    at org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.Form.process(Form.java:938) [Form.class:6.15.0]
    at org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.StatelessForm.process(StatelessForm.java:96) [StatelessForm.class:6.15.0]
    at org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.Form.onFormSubmitted(Form.java:770) [Form.class:6.15.0]
    at org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.Form.onFormSubmitted(Form.java:703) [Form.class:6.15.0]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.7.0_21]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) ~[?:1.7.0_21]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.7.0_21]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601) ~[?:1.7.0_21]
    at org.apache.wicket.RequestListenerInterface.internalInvoke(RequestListenerInterface.java:258) [RequestListenerInterface.class:6.15.0]
    at org.apache.wicket.RequestListenerInterface.invoke(RequestListenerInterface.java:216) [RequestListenerInterface.class:6.15.0]
    at org.apache.wicket.core.request.handler.ListenerInterfaceRequestHandler.invokeListener(ListenerInterfaceRequestHandler.java:243) [ListenerInterfaceRequestHandler.class:6.15.0]
    at org.apache.wicket.core.request.handler.ListenerInterfaceRequestHandler.respond(ListenerInterfaceRequestHandler.java:236) [ListenerInterfaceRequestHandler.class:6.15.0]
    at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle$HandlerExecutor.respond(RequestCycle.java:862) [RequestCycle$HandlerExecutor.class:6.15.0]
    at org.apache.wicket.request.RequestHandlerStack.execute(RequestHandlerStack.java:64) [RequestHandlerStack.class:6.15.0]
    at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.execute(RequestCycle.java:261) [RequestCycle.class:6.15.0]
    at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.processRequest(RequestCycle.java:218) [RequestCycle.class:6.15.0]
    at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.processRequestAndDetach(RequestCycle.java:289) [RequestCycle.class:6.15.0]
    at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.processRequestCycle(WicketFilter.java:259) [WicketFilter.class:6.15.0]
    at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.processRequest(WicketFilter.java:201) [WicketFilter.class:6.15.0]
    at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.doFilter(WicketFilter.java:282) [WicketFilter.class:6.15.0]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) [catalina.jar:8.0.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) [catalina.jar:8.0.8]
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.web.Log4jServletFilter.doFilter(Log4jServletFilter.java:66) [Log4jServletFilter.class:2.0-rc1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) [catalina.jar:8.0.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) [catalina.jar:8.0.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219) [catalina.jar:8.0.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106) [catalina.jar:8.0.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:503) [catalina.jar:8.0.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:136) [catalina.jar:8.0.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:78) [catalina.jar:8.0.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610) [catalina.jar:8.0.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88) [catalina.jar:8.0.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:526) [catalina.jar:8.0.8]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1033) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.8]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:652) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.8]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:222) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.8]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1566) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.8]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1523) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.8]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [?:1.7.0_21]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [?:1.7.0_21]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-util.jar:8.0.8]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722) [?:1.7.0_21]
```

The driver is also in the lib folder of the app in `WEB-INF/lib` could this cause the exception? I am using Java 7 and version 4 of the MSSQL JDBC driver.

**Update**

If I write

```
try {
    Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
} catch (final ClassNotFoundException e) {
    // Should not happen.
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

before, I get the connection. Why is it so?

Comment: What is the name of the driver jar you copied ?

Comment: The name is sqljdbc4.jar

Comment: It is the same that I use locally.

Comment: Because you need to load the driver class first to use it. DriverManager makes use of this class. But if you are using server (Tomcat in your case) you should be using DataSource to get connection.

Comment: But not if I use a JDBC 4 driver, as I do. And as said above: It was always working on Jetty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I got the reason. Tomcat tries to prevent memory leaks due to some particular java/javax apis and it seems that the sql server driver is one of them. If you disable that feature it should load the driver automatically. To disable, modify the server.xml JreMemoryLeakPreventionListener entry as below.

```
<Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.JreMemoryLeakPreventionListener" driverManagerProtection="false" />
```

Comment: This was exactly the solution on a decently recent setup (Ubuntu 20.04, Tomcat 9). Sad that we need to disable a protection as a workaround.