# When working with tomcat, how are JDBC Drivers loaded?

Tags: java, tomcat, jdbc

I am using Eclipse and tomcat 7.  I have little experience with either product and for that matter Java itself.  I was trying to connect to a derby database from a Servlet.  Initially, all I had in my `doGet()` is the following:

```
conn = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionURL);
```

I have connectionURL defined as

```
static private String connectionURL = "jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/seconddb";
```

Then I added the following to the Build Path and Deployment Assembly.

```
C:\DERBY\db-derby-10.10.1.1-bin\lib\derbyclient.jar
```

That is all I did. I sort of assumed that Tomcat will find the driver class and load it.  I got the following error

```
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/seconddb
```

Then I went on to add the following code in doGet() to load the driver class:

```
    try {
           Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver");
        }
        catch(ClassNotFoundException ex) {
           System.out.println("Error: unable to load driver class!");
           System.exit(1);
    }
```

Now it worked.  I thought that after Java 1.4 there was no need to explicitly load JDBC driver class.  So what am I doing wrong here?  I have given the entire code below.

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    Connection conn = null;

    try {
           Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver");
        }
        catch(ClassNotFoundException ex) {
           System.out.println("Error: unable to load driver class!");
           System.exit(1);
    }

    try {
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionURL);
        //DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/testdb;create=true");
    }
    catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    PrintWriter p = response.getWriter ();
    p.println("Connected to database");

    try {
        if (conn != null) {
            conn.close();
        }
    }
    catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I am using java 1.7

Comment: Driver auto-loading was introduced with Java 6 (JDBC 4), not Java 1.4.

Comment: But does whatever version of Derby you're using support the driver detection model?

Comment: I am using 10.10.1.1 which I had downloaded not too long ago.  I would think that it should support the driver detection.  I use it in a non web context and I do not have to explicitly load the driver.

Comment: I am using db-derby 10.10.1.1 which I had downloaded not too long ago.  So I would think it should support the driver detection.  I use it in a non-web context and I do not have to explicitly load the driver.

Comment: Seems like a legitimate question.  I gave all the code and clearly explained my problem.  So why is it a -1.  Is this to discourage people from asking questions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot really explain why, but here is how I do :

- if the driver is located in the war, I must call `Class.forName("...Driver");` in in initialization method somewhere in the web application.
- if the driver is located in Tomcat libraries, it is automacally loaded when I need it.

I know it's more a rule of thumb than a clear explaination, but my knowledge in class loading does not allow me to a better answer ...

Comment: For me putting the jar file in the tomcat/lib does not seem to be working either.  I also had a look at a similar posting, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23912885/mssql-driver-is-not-loaded-by-tomcat?rq=1 - but that solution did not work for me. For now, I have to contend with loading the class, untiul I find the cause.

Answer (score 0):

Your Derby driver doesn't support the JDBC 4 auto-loading, so you have to do it manually. Try to find a more up to date version.

Comment: I will try an updated version.  However, I was using the Derby client JAR in a non-web context (plain java program) and I did not have to explicitly load the class.

Answer (score 0):

I could be wrong here but in your second code sample connectionURL

> static private String connectionURL = "jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/seconddb";

doesn't include "create=true"; to complete the statement. In your full code sample it's included, but commented out.