# Get error java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:sqlserver://localhost;databaseName=ABC;integratedSecurity=true on Production

Tags: java, sql-server

I created a Web Application using Java, JSP,Tomcat via Eclipse.

1. When running the Application on my Windows development Env, it works fine. database connection is fine (sqljdbc42.jar in Lib via Eclipse) The test db is on my Window development PC 
   Link: http://localhost:8080/App/
2. To test the db connection on Production is working right, I have a Java file (not related to my project, but using same db driver and url. It's just for test DB connection on production), it connects to db which is located on production correctly.
3. However, after I upload my war file (from local development environment) to Tomcat WebApps folder, I got the error in title, the db on production is not connected successfully.

I use the following drivers and url for db connection

```
drivers=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver

url=jdbc:sqlserver://localhost;databaseName=ABC;integratedSecurity=true
```

In the above url string, I have tried localhost as above, also tried production IP address, Server name, `localhost:1433`, `localhost\\MSSQLSERVER`, all get the same error

I have below in `ClassPath` in production site:

```
C:\sqljdbc42.jar;C:\microsoft-mssqlserver.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_201\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_201\bin;.
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: the driver jar is not in included your war file

Comment: Hi Laazo,  thanks for your feedback. I have sqljdbc42.jar set in ClassPath in production site: C:\sqljdbc42.jar;C:\microsoft-mssqlserver.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_201\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_201\bin;. that should help, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check the classloader paths for tomcat server. Regarding the [docs](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/class-loader-howto.html), your server will hope finding sqlserver driver jar (`sqljdbc42.jar`) in the following places:

1. Bootstrap classes of your JVM (`$JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/ext`)
2. `/WEB-INF/classes` of your web application
3. `/WEB-INF/lib/*.jar` of your web application
4. System class loader classes (described through `CLASSPATH` environment variable)
5. Common class loader classes (`$CATALINA_BASE/lib` and `$CATALINA_HOME/lib`)

So, best options you can try are:

- copying the jar to `$JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/ext` (#1)
- or configuring your build so that, the jar is copied in `/WEB-INF/lib/` (#3)

Number#2 is suitable for java classes; does not fit your case.

Number#4 and #5 are more likely for the use of tomcat's own structure, but still it is **perfectly legal** if you want to put the jar in.

**Further Edit:** For some reason, there are [cases](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23915145/4636715) Tomcat may prevent sqlserver driver for the sake of preventing memory leaks. So, if you're sure the jar is on the classpath by applying the solutions mentioned in beforehand this post; you may also try to check with adding the following to `server/.xml` to disable that leak check:

```
<Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.JreMemoryLeakPreventionListener" driverManagerProtection="false" />
```

Comment: Edited the answer, since your `JAVA_HOME` looks more like a `JRE_HOME`, you may try `CATALINA_HOME/lib` for placing the jar (even if it is not the prettiest and distributable way to me). If no solution still, please check the **further edit** part added.